# UIAlertAction doesn't perform action after archive and export as adhoc

Tags: swift, ios8.1, uialertaction

I am creating an alert in response to discovering a specific BLE characteristic. This alert has 2 UIAlertAction buttons. Each does its action correctly when building from Xcode (v 6.1.1 6A2008a) but when archiving and exporting using an Ad Hoc provisioning profile, one button will do its action but the other will not.

Some code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            (action) in
            debugData.addToLog("OK button pressed")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Not Now", style: .Default) {
            (action) in
            debugData.addToLog("Not Now button pressed")
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        debugData.addToLog("Building alert")
        appDelegate.nav.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

debugData goes to a hidden view that I use a UIGesture to reveal. Xcode's output will show `Building Alert` and `OK Button pressed` and `Not Now button pressed` but archiving and exporting will only show `Building alert` and `Not Now button pressed`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that going to the project Target > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Optimization Level and setting Release to `None [-Onone]` will get both actions to perform correctly. Seems to be a Swift compiler error.